# How to execute tasks based on a subfolder with Grunt and Grunt-Watch

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I want to be able to have different subprojects inside my main project. For example:

```
-- my-project/
   - Gruntfile.js
   - subproject1/
     - index.html
     - scss/
       - main.scss
   - subproject2/
     - index.html
     - scss/
       - main.scss
```

I want to be able to modify a file in subproject1 without triggering subproject2 tasks.

As of right now I'm configuring my gruntfile like so:

```
watch: {
    subproject1: {
        files: ['subproject1/*.html', 'subproject1/scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'premailer:subproject1']
    },
    subproject2: {
        files: ['subproject2/*.html', 'subproject2/scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'premailer:subproject2']
    }
},

premailer: {
    subproject1: {
        options: {
            css: 'subproject1/css/main.css',
            verbose: false
        },
        files: [
            {
            'subproject1/dist/index.html' : 'subproject1/index.html'
            }
        ]
    },
    subproject2: {
        options: {
            css: 'subproject2/css/main.css',
            verbose: false
        },
        files: [
            {
            'subproject2/dist/index.html' : 'subproject2/index.html'
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically specify to grunt what task to run depending on file modified (eg, I modify *folder*/index.html, then run premailer:*folder*) or is this the only way to achieve it ?

Comment: Check this section of the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed), i think is what you need.

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to simply build the modified file, but call a different task. Using the event to do so is not encouraged. Even the docs says: **The watch event is not intended for replacing the standard Grunt API for configuring and running tasks. If you're trying to run tasks from within the watch event you're more than likely doing it wrong**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check all folders in your main folder inside your Gruntfile, using the grunt.file methods (docs [here](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file)), create an array of subproject names and then using forEach to create your task dynamically.

Something like this should go:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var mycwd = "./";

    var tempFileList = grunt.file.expand(
        { filter: function (src) {
            if (grunt.file.isDir(src) == true) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } },
        [ mycwd + "!(Gruntfile.js|node_modules|package.json)" ] // structure to analyse
    );

    // I create an empty array to put all elements in, once cleaned.
    var fileList = [];

    tempFileList.forEach(function(url){
        var cwd = url;
        cwd = cwd.replace(mycwd, "");
        fileList.push(cwd);
    })

    var watchObject = {};
    var premailerObject = {};

    fileList.forEach(function(name) {
        watchObject[name] = {
            files: [name + '/*.html', name + '/scss/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass', 'premailer:' + name]
        };
        var filesObject = {};
        filesObject[name+'/css/main.css'] = name + '/index.html';
        premailerObject[name] = {
            options: { css: name + '/css/main.css', verbose: false },
            files: [ filesObject ]
        };
    });

    var configObject = {
        watch: watchObject,
        premailer: premailerObject
    };

    // just to check the final structure
    console.log(configObject); 

    grunt.initConfig(configObject);

};
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I ended up doing.